# Sencha Native: module cordova/plugin/geolocation not found

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, sencha-touch-2.1, cordova-plugins

Added geolocation plugin using

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation

I see that config.xml for iOS contains

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

I've made cordova prepare && cordova compile

But when I do

```
        var geo = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/geolocation');
```

I still see message in console:
module cordova/plugin/geolocation not found

Already tried to add/remove platform/all plugins. Didn't help.

What should I do?

UPDATE. Just updated cordova to 3.5 and now got new message:
       Error: Module org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Coordinates does not exist.

Application fails at start. Already tried to remove/add everything from plugins to entire cordova support at sencha app.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: @TWilly I've refused to use Sencha+Cordova and turned to native iOS project.